# OpenSUSE: how to login to shell without /bin/bash --login ? (automatically)

Tags: linux, shell, opensuse

I'm programming in Ruby, on latest OpenSUSE.

Every time I open new tab (which I do a lot during the day) - I need to type:

```
/bin/bash --login
```

Otherwise it won't load all my settings.

Tried to create alias for that, but aliaces are saved into `.bashrc` file, so they don't work until I log in.

Is there a way to have terminal login right after I opened a new terminal window?

Tried to make a Bash file:

```
!/bin/bash
xterm -e "/bin/bash --login"
```

But I can't go to desktop every time I need to open a new tab.

Does anyone know how to set up OpenSUSE properly?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this question fits Stack Overflow.  You may have been doing some programming in Ruby, but there is no Ruby code in this question, and your question relates to administering OpenSUSE.  Please ask the question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: It is a Super User type of question but will be a duplicate there.

Comment: I flagged it to be moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login bash reads `~/.bash_profile`, interactive bash - `~/.bashrc`. See [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) for more details.

When you open a terminal window it starts bash in the interactive mode which makes bash read `~/.bashrc`. Settings from `~/.bash_profile` are normally read when you log into the desktop, so that when `~/.bash_profile` is changed you need to re-login for the changes to apply.

People often make `~/.bash_profile` invoke `~/.bashrc` as well, so that you get the same environment in both modes.

Comment: yep, works. added `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi` to `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @SergeVinogradoff or as a bash one-liner: `[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc`